# How to get default config of pylint?

Tags: python, pylint, pylintrc

I will use this simple Python file for illustrating my problem:

```
import os

for i in range( -500, 0 ):
    print i
```

I run Pylint on this file and get one message:

```
$ pylint foobar.py
************* Module foobar
W:  1, 0: Unused import os (unused-import)
```

Now I want to disable warning messages of the type `unused-import`. But I want to add that on top of the default configuration of Pylint.

I thought this gives me the default config of Pylint, cause help of `--generate-rcfile` says it generates current configuration:

```
$ pylint --generate-rcfile > pylintrc
```

When I run Pylint again on the same file, I now get a lot more messages:

```
************* Module foobar
C:  3, 0: No space allowed after bracket
for i in range( -500, 0 ):
              ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  3, 0: No space allowed before bracket
for i in range( -500, 0 ):
                        ^ (bad-whitespace)
C:  1, 0: Missing module docstring (missing-docstring)
W:  1, 0: Unused import os (unused-import)
```

Why is the `bad-whitespace` message getting triggered only after the pylintrc was generated? Is `bad-whitespace` disabled by default? How do I get the actual default config of pylint?

So, if the `--generate-rcfile` is not giving me the default config, what is the config options it outputs? How do I get the default config of Pylint in the pylintrc format? So that I can add my settings on top of that.

Answer (score 4):

Note that the documentation for `--generate-rcfile` (from `pylint --help`) states:

> --generate-rcfile
>
> Generate a sample configuration file **according to the
> current configuration**. You can put other options
> before this one to get them in the generated
> configuration.

(Emphasis mine.) In other words, `--generate-rc-file` *depends on your existing configuration*.  It generates a configuration file that merges the default configuration with your existing one.

If you instead want the default, base configuration with no changes, **you therefore should run it with an empty existing configuration**.  You can do that either by temporarily renaming `~/.pylintrc` or by running `pylint --rcfile="" --generate-rcfile`.

Comment: Please read the question thoroughly, this is something the OP did run.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I am aware that OP tried it, but I believe that the OP is misunderstanding what it does, hence the "with emphasis added".  Additionally, OP did not run it with `--rcfile=""`.

Comment: @bugmenot123 I've updated my answer for clarity.  If you still disagree, please provide a counterexample that shows that it is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I just check the [pylintrc file in the source tree of the pylint
project](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylintrc). Not sure whether they are really the default values, but appears to be pretty close.